# Como substituir valores por NA usando codificação de elementos (e não posição)?

Tags: r, array

estou com dificuldades de substituir valores em um vetor por NA, mas usando a codificação do tratamento (e nao a posição).
Um exemplo simples e hipotético do meu problema é (meu conjunto de dados é muito grande e tenho varios sets, entao nao dá pra fazer manual):

```
filhos <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15)
peso <- c(55, 58, 76, 42, 68, 80, 47, 55, 85)
dados <- as.data.frame(cbind(filhos, peso))
set <- c(3, 6, 11)
New <- dados$peso; New
    [1] 55 58 76 42 68 80 47 55 85
```

O que eu quero é o resultado:

```
    [1] 55 NA 76 NA 68 80 NA 55 85
```

no qual o NA é referente aos filhos 3, 6, e 11.
Eu tentei algumas opções que não deram certo, como:

```
New[set] <- NA; New            # usa a posicao e nao o codigo do individuo
    [1] 55 58 NA 42 68 NA 47 55 85 NA NA       

# ou
ifelse(dados$filhos==set, NA, New)   # erro = vetor New nao tem a mesma dimensao de set
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o comando `%in%` na comparação:

```
filhos <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15)
peso <- c(55, 58, 76, 42, 68, 80, 47, 55, 85)
dados <- as.data.frame(cbind(filhos, peso))
set <- c(3, 6, 11)
New <- dados$peso; New

ifelse(dados$filhos %in% set, NA, New)
[1] 55 NA 76 NA 68 80 NA 55 85
```

O `%in%` verifica se cada elemento de um vetor está contido dentro de um outro vetor.